# Prism dependency injection interface object gets null value

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have registered an interface as prism dependency injection in my app.cs file.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
         Container.RegisterType<ISqliteCallsService, SqliteCallsService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
```

So when I create an object of this dependency interface it becomes null in a separate public class 'SampleClass.cs'.

```
 public class SampleClass
{
    ISqliteCallsService _sqliteCallsService;
    public SampleClass(ISqliteCallsService sqliteCallsService)
    {
        _sqliteCallsService = sqliteCallsService;
        _sqliteCallsService.SyncOfflineFeedbacktoServer();
    }
```

Here `_sqliteCallsService` gets a null value.

Comment: How do you create the `SampleClass` instance?

Comment: Sorry had made a typo in constructor name, have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies are normally injected via constructors or properties so that a class has a reference to the dependency. They are not magically substituted in as method parameters as you've done here.

You need to resolve the SampleClass using the DI Container and give the resolved class a way of exposing it's dependencies so that they can be resolved. The simplest solution is this:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    private ISqlLitCallService _sqlService;

    public SampleClass(ISqliteCallsService sqlService)
    { 
       _sqlService = sqlService;
    }

    public ConnectivitySyncMainLHBackgroundingCode()
    {
        _sqliteCallsService.SyncOfflineFeedbacktoServer();
    }
}
```

In your calling class:

```
var s = Container.Resolve<SampleClass>();
s.ConnectivitySyncMainLHBackgroundingCode();
```

Comment: Sorry I had made a typo, the constructor name is SampleClass and not ConnectivitySyncMainLHBackgroundingCode

Comment: And how are you instantiating your SampleClass? You need to use Container.Resolve<SampleClass>().

Comment: I was instantiating it like this from a class present In Droid project:

ISqliteCallsService sqliteCallsService = DependencyService.Get<ISqliteCallsService>();
var oBackground = new SampleClass(sqliteCallsService);

Comment: In that case it looks like you haven't hooked up the DependencyService correctly, if DependencyService.Get is returning null.

Comment: In RegisterTypes method I have done it as follows : 
  Container.Resolve<Func<ISqliteCallsService,SampleClass>>();

Comment: The DependencyService is a different simple IoC provided by Xamarin.  If you haven't registered your types with that service then it will not be able to resolve them.  Don't use that.  Use the Unity container instead.

Comment: `public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
     {
                container.RegisterType<ISqliteCallsService, SqliteCallsService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
               
                
            }`

We had Registered dependency service as above eg. in app.cs using prism iUnityContainer so is this the correct way of registering?

Comment: That's correct. What Brian is trying to say is that you're registering correctly with the IUnityContainer but then trying to resolve your class with the DependencyService.Get call, and they're two different things. You shouldn't be using DependencyService, you should be using (Unity)Container.Resolve

Comment: I was able to solve it based on solution provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45315763 

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Can we use dependency injection in MessagingCenter with Prism Application?

I have a long running task, need to call a service using DI